# Limit the creation of tags

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I wish to create a taxonomy where the administrator users limit which terms can be tagged.

Suppose I have a vocabulary containing the following terms:

- Football
- Golf
- Snooker

I want the tag autocomplete to show the tags that can be used. If I typed "Foo", the autocomplete should show "Football"; if I typed "Basketball," the autocomplete would not show anything, the node would submit, but no term is created.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the [Content Taxonomy](http://drupal.org/project/content_taxonomy) modules provides the ability to do this.

Without this, you'd have to implement [hook_nodeapi('presave')](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) and remove terms that don't exist yet.

Not even Drupal 7 seems to allow this without a contrib module, even though it does have specific edit terms permission for each vocabulary. Strange.